# this hook_uninstall isn't deleting fields in my module!

Tags: 7, entities

I've trying to make a simple module that creates a node-type and adds a few custom fields to it with the Field API.

[Here is my module's .install](http://pastebin.com/fectHiwg)

[Here is my module's .module](http://pastebin.com/B3zYsVk9)

The module installs just fine. After changing some things in my hook_install_fields, I disabled the module and uninstalled. When I try to re-enable the module, drush prompts me that one of the fields already exists and is active. **My problem is that hook_uninstall doesn't seem to be deleting the fields from the database.** If I manually delete the field tables from the database, I'm able to re-enable the module without error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: with is there an underscore? _customer_testimony_uninstall()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your uninstall hook is incorrectly named and not invoked.

Current (line 137):

```
function _customer_testimony_uninstall() {
```

Try change it to:

```
function customer_testimony_uninstall() {
```

(No underscore in the beginning)

Comment: This is right: Hook's names don't start with an underscore.